# Save each element from ArrayList into new line with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I have a POJO:

```
public class Game {

    private String title;

    private Set<String> genres;

    private String size;

    private List<String> screenshots;
}
```

I want to save Game object to JSON.
`ObjectMapper`configuration:

```
public static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
            .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
            .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
```

Save object to JSON:
`mapper.writeValue(new File(PATH), game)`

And JSON looks like:

```
{
  "title" : "Dead Cells",
  "genres" : [ "Action" ],
  "size" : "761M",
  "screenshots" : [ "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/af9mFH4XinZ7f6dx-Ygm9molYPAcMHhhZyQ0udDBd9S9-44v_VBdeA0rjSlQyJRpQg=w1440-h620-rw", "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mo0CZaV_aGflOPB8Tzo697l1WoZuoYUN9TiPMWq0zE29v_I99n1Qg185MfHrU-53nxAG=w1440-h620-rw", "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/FEiHmVyoT1MU3rbAxSkE_aNDuXBuo3YHQOnqfMAfehS-d4k6CvxuyxpX6KKSbJp3Xv28=w1440-h620-rw", "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/3Zg_EtwMpt-vWNBTdCNE7hP8M6qeDMq91HKfx70FSJ5tVAsPxHkTYWGiCwvHg5ucMykK=w1440-h620-rw", "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/A9K6iPYty9IvkzeO_29ONdPAnFFs1BBzk6w-dAf1s5JgpZFMpxc5wpbz07fzovJWxlzO=w1440-h620-rw" ]
}
```

As you can see, all screenshots prints like one string, but I want the result like this:

```
{
  "title" : "Dead Cells",
  "genres" : [ "Action" ],
  "size" : "761M",
  "screenshots" : [ "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/af9mFH4XinZ7f6dx=w1440-h620-rw", 
                    "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/I99n1Qg185MfHrU-53nxAG=w1440-h620-rw", 
                    "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d4k6CvxuyxpX6KKSbJp3Xv28=w1440-h620-rw", 
                    "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/wvHg5ucMykK=w1440-h620-rw", 
                  ]
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: you need delete the last comma of your second json to make it wright

Answer (score 2):

You can use writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter of ObjectMapper like the follow code:

```
Game game = new Game();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
File file = new File("pretty-print.json");
mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(file, game);
```

The output of your data is:

```
{
  "title" : "Dead Cells",
  "genres" : [ "Action" ],
  "size" : "761M",
  "screenshots" : [ 
"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/af9mFH4XinZ7f6dx-Ygm9molYPAcMHhhZyQ0udDBd9S9-44v_VBdeA0rjSlQyJRpQg=w1440-h620-rw", 
"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mo0CZaV_aGflOPB8Tzo697l1WoZuoYUN9TiPMWq0zE29v_I99n1Qg185MfHrU-53nxAG=w1440-h620-rw", 
"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/FEiHmVyoT1MU3rbAxSkE_aNDuXBuo3YHQOnqfMAfehS-d4k6CvxuyxpX6KKSbJp3Xv28=w1440-h620-rw", 
"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/3Zg_EtwMpt-vWNBTdCNE7hP8M6qeDMq91HKfx70FSJ5tVAsPxHkTYWGiCwvHg5ucMykK=w1440-h620-rw", 
"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/A9K6iPYty9IvkzeO_29ONdPAnFFs1BBzk6w-dAf1s5JgpZFMpxc5wpbz07fzovJWxlzO=w1440-h620-rw" ]
}
```

Comment: what problems you get？